# A C program for solving a labyrinth problem

Tags: c, recursion

I have to write a program which reads numbers M and N that are on an interval [1,30] and a labyrinth made from M X N cells (M rows and N columns) and prints out a path from top left cell to bottom right cell.

An example input:

> ```
> 4 3  
> 1101 0110 1110  
> 1110 1001 0010  
> 1000 0101 0011  
> 1001 0101 0111
> ```

The cell and its walls are described with four 1 or 0, 1 being that a wall is present and 0 meaning that the wall is not present and we can go through. The first digit tells us if the left wall is present, the second one tells us about the upper, the third one about the right one and the fourth about the the bottom wall.

So the above map looks like this:

> ```
> +---+---+---+
> |       |   |
> +---+   +   +
> |   |       |
> +   +---+   +
> |           |
> +   +---+---+
> |           |
> +---+---+---+
> ```

The path is described as the sequence of digits 0 (left), 1 (upwards), 2 (right) and 3 (downwards) without spaces in between, therefore the solution to the path above is "232300322".

So far I have been able to put the labyrinth into a 2d char array as seen below, but I am not sure how to go on from here. I had an idea to use a recursive function called bool areWeThereYet() which would return true if we have gotten to the end, but I am not sure if this is the right approach, since I am not sure how to correctly implement it, so that it prints out the path.

I also have to mention that there is only one correct path in all the test cases.

I am asking for somebody to guide me through the problem and I will be grateful for all the help I receive.

```
    int rows,columns;

    scanf("%d%d",&rows,&columns);
    char currentChar;
    char labyrinth[rows][columns * 4];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns * 4; j++){
            currentChar = getchar();
            if(currentChar == ' ' || currentChar == '\n'){
                currentChar = getchar();
            }
            labyrinth[i][j] = currentChar;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not accept the answer you got, so you seem to not be satisfied with it. Your problem is that some users have voted that your question is "too broad" and it is now in a status "on hold" which means that there cannot be any more answers. To change that you need to demonstrate that you have a more specific problem than "How to solve the whole task?". In order to change that I propose to simplify the task so much that you can solve it and then make it harder step by step. When you get stuck with a simple solution show it here and ask again. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler

Comment: For example change the task to be restricted to 1x2 mazes or 2x1 mazes. Surely you can come up with a solution for that. Then you make it harder by allowing larger mazes, but still guarantee that there is always only one exit from each square (except for the entry one, the one through which the path ends up in the  square), let's call that the "obvious maze" simplification. The point is that the actual creative work for this assignment starts AFTER finding that simple solution and the details you provided in your question indicated that you haven't even come close. I will reopen-vote then.

Comment: If you cannot solve the obvious maze simplification, then it is time to ask about somethign more basic which gets you stuck, that however would be a much more basic and very different question. A more basic problem could be to actually use the data your code has read in. Maybe demonstrate (to yourself), that you can really analyse stored mazes by first writing code to output them in ascii art, like the edit by somebody else in your question. Next would be to write code which checks wether it is an extremely obvious maze, i.e. all squares have at most two exits.

Comment: There are two general things you can do to put potential answereres in a good mood. 1) make a [mcve] (only of your input code or of the best attempt you have) instead of showing a code fragment 2) take the [tour]. Many users get quite annoyed if you skip one of the two.

Comment: I hope you get this interesting question reopened. Becaue I want to join in with @Joshua to help you according to the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions At least I think that is what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a basic 2D search. While there are fancy search algorithms, you can use a simple one.

You an do this recursively, but on larger grids you run out of stack and have to use a queue.

1) Make an array for storing the distance to each node; it's easiest if it uses the same access as the grid. Initialize to INT_MAX or some other infinite value.

2) Make another array to store the reverse path; each node will store how we got here for the cost in array 1.

3) Begin at the starting point; store 0 for distance and self for previous node

4) For each available move, if the current path length is less than the path length in the grid, store current path + 1 in distance array and this node in reverse path array. Call or push #4 with this location.

5) After the recursive #4 has completely finished, construct an array with length of the value in the finish location in the distance array. Your path is still in absolute coordinates.

6) Iterate over the path in the location array starting from the finish node copying the values into the array created into #5. This results in the path from finish to start being stored in this array.

7) Reverse this array to get the path from start to finish.

8) In printing the path, use a loop with a simple decoder that converts the absolute coordinates to relative coordinates. We need to start the iteration at 1 rather than 0 when doing this.

Comment: Re "*You an do this recursively, but on larger grids you run out of stack and have to use a queue*", A queue (as opposed to a stack) changes it from a deapth-first search into a breadth-first search, which is far better because DFS can fail quite spectacularly.

Comment: @ikegami: Well he did put [tag:recursion] in the question.

Comment: I"m not sure why you said that. I was applauding your suggestion to use a BFS.